# How to Filter paginated table with "Picnet Table filter"?

Tags: list, displaytag, tablefilter

I am using "Picnet Table filter" for filtering my tables.

I am using display tag for displaying my table data.

I have hnadreds of records to show in the table and hence I have used pagination where page size is 50.

I am showing 50 records per page.

When I use this plugin to filter the data in the table, it only filters data on the current page.

Is there any way we can make "Picnet Table filter" to filter the data on the entire list rather than in just the page?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what are you using for pagination, are you using any framework ?